# How can libxml2 be used to parse data from XML?

Tags: c, xml, parsing, libxml2

I have looked around at the libxml2 code samples and I am confused on how to piece them all together.

What are the steps needed when using libxml2 to just parse or extract data from an XML file?

I would like to get hold of, and possibly store information for, certain attributes. How is this done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you first need to create a Parse tree. Maybe this article can help, look through the section which says [How to Parse a Tree with Libxml2](http://www.developer.com/xml/article.php/3729826/Libxml2-Everything-You-Need-in-an-XML-Library.htm).

Comment: I would have found this useful the other day, but as it goes I had code to work from and search engine. As far as I've worked it out, you'll also want to read the documentation for the `xmlGetProp` function which will give the values for the properties of a node, ie `<node property="value"/>`.

Comment: Thanks James, I will have a look.

Answer (score 5):

libxml2 provides various examples showing basic usage.

http://xmlsoft.org/examples/index.html

For your stated goals, tree1.c would probably be most relevant.

> tree1.c: Navigates a tree to print
>   element names
>
> Parse a file to a tree, use
>   xmlDocGetRootElement() to get the root
>   element, then walk the document and
>   print all the element name in document
>   order.

http://xmlsoft.org/examples/tree1.c

Once you have an xmlNode struct for an element, the "properties" member is a linked list of attributes.  Each xmlAttr object has a "name" and "children" object (which are the name/value for that attribute, respectively), and a "next" member which points to the next attribute (or null for the last one).

http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlNode

http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-tree.html#xmlAttr

Comment: Thanks for this. So once I have got all the elements, how can I get to their attributes?

Answer (score 3):

I found these two resources helpful when I was learning to use libxml2 to build a rss feed parser.

[Tutorial with SAX interface](http://www.jamesh.id.au/articles/libxml-sax/libxml-sax.html)

[Tutorial using the DOM Tree](http://xmlsoft.org/tutorial/) (code example for getting an attribute value included)

Answer (score 3):

Here, I mentioned complete process to extract XML/HTML data from file on windows platform.

1. First download pre-compiled **.dll** form http://xmlsoft.org/sources/win32/
2. Also download its dependency **iconv.dll** and **zlib1.dll** from the same page
3. Extract all .zip files into the same directory. For Ex: D:\demo\
4. Copy **iconv.dll**, **zlib1.dll** and **libxml2.dll** into **c:\windows\system32** deirectory
5. Make **libxml_test.cpp** file and copy following code into that file.

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <string.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <libxml/HTMLparser.h>

   void traverse_dom_trees(xmlNode * a_node)
   {
       xmlNode *cur_node = NULL;

       if(NULL == a_node)
       {
           //printf("Invalid argument a_node %p\n", a_node);
           return;
       }

       for (cur_node = a_node; cur_node; cur_node = cur_node->next) 
       {
           if (cur_node->type == XML_ELEMENT_NODE) 
           {
               /* Check for if current node should be exclude or not */
               printf("Node type: Text, name: %s\n", cur_node->name);
           }
           else if(cur_node->type == XML_TEXT_NODE)
           {
               /* Process here text node, It is available in cpStr :TODO: */
               printf("node type: Text, node content: %s,  content length %d\n", (char *)cur_node->content, strlen((char *)cur_node->content));
           }
           traverse_dom_trees(cur_node->children);
       }
   }

   int main(int argc, char **argv) 
   {
       htmlDocPtr doc;
       xmlNode *roo_element = NULL;

       if (argc != 2)  
       {
           printf("\nInvalid argument\n");
           return(1);
       }

       /* Macro to check API for match with the DLL we are using */
       LIBXML_TEST_VERSION    

       doc = htmlReadFile(argv[1], NULL, HTML_PARSE_NOBLANKS | HTML_PARSE_NOERROR | HTML_PARSE_NOWARNING | HTML_PARSE_NONET);
       if (doc == NULL) 
       {
           fprintf(stderr, "Document not parsed successfully.\n");
           return 0;
       }

       roo_element = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc);

       if (roo_element == NULL) 
       {
           fprintf(stderr, "empty document\n");
           xmlFreeDoc(doc);
           return 0;
       }

       printf("Root Node is %s\n", roo_element->name);
       traverse_dom_trees(roo_element);

       xmlFreeDoc(doc);       // free document
       xmlCleanupParser();    // Free globals
       return 0;
   }
   ```
6. Open Visual Studio Command Promt
7. Go To D:\demo directory
8. execute **cl libxml_test.cpp /I".\libxml2-2.7.8.win32\include"  /I".\iconv-1.9.2.win32\include" /link libxml2-2.7.8.win32\lib\libxml2.lib** command
9. Run binary using **libxml_test.exe test.html** command(Here test.html may be any valid HTML file)

Answer (score 0):

You can refere [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64099009/12214121) answer.
here they store data into structure format and use further by passing structure address to a function.

### You can find detail code in c for use.

### code ->> [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64099009/12214121)