# Parse XML with C

Tags: c, xml, xml-parsing, libxml2

Hi I am trying to use C to parse xml, but all the examples I can find are using a file to get the xml, I have the xml already loaded into a variable and I want libxml2 to take the xml from there instead of a file.... but I can't figure out how!

Any help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can libxml2 be used to parse data from XML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465965/how-can-libxml2-be-used-to-parse-data-from-xml)

Comment: There is actually an example on their website that does exactly what you want: http://www.xmlsoft.org/examples/parse3.c.

Comment: @Cédric: not exactly a duplicate. The OP is trying to parse an XML string, from memory, and not a XML file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [this example:](http://xmlsoft.org/examples/index.html#parse3.c) using [XmlReadMemory](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-parser.html#xmlReadMemory)

Answer (score 1):

Look at the signature of [xmlParseDoc](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-parser.html#xmlParseDoc) function.

It takes `const xmlChar * cur` as a parameter, and xmlChar is actually defined as `unsigned char` [here](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-xmlstring.html#xmlChar)