# How to implement a parser in C for xml based structured language?

Tags: c++, c, xml-parsing, expat-parser

I need to implement a simple parser in C (or C++ if C is discouraged for this application) that will read a xml file which will only contain a few elements (that's why called it xml based) i.e., only 4 root elements and and less than 5 child elements totally.
Is it easy to implement or should I use a library like expat? And if it is possible can someone tell me how I can about the process?

Comment: Use a library. If you don't know anything about parsing in general, then definitely use a library.

Comment: Do not underestimate the complexity of writing a parser for even quite a simple language. Use a library, it's much easier.

Comment: My task just got more complicated. My data is in the form of a XML based binary encoding scheme. So from this I should either directly parse the transmitted binary representation or restore the XML representation. Can someone give some details on the basics of data parsing?

Answer (score 2):

Use libxml or libexpat.
There are millions, trillions of examples you can find on net, or even at StackOverflow.
Have a look at this: [How can libxml2 be used to parse data from XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5465965/how-can-libxml2-be-used-to-parse-data-from-xml)

Answer (score -1):

or use google protobuf, 
although it is not xml-based, but it fast.

Comment: It also won't parse XML which makes it useless to the questioner.

Comment: yes, just in case that XML isn't real requirement.