# Get URL from html page - objective

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, html-parsing

I need to get URL from loaded HTML page. Here is HTML tag where placed my URL

```
<a class="top_nav_link" id="logout_link" href="https://login.vk.com/?act=logout&hash=29327318c645d49a48&from_host=vk.com&from_protocol=http" onclick="if (!checkEvent(event)) { ge('logout_form').submit(); return false; }">
```

And URL: "https://login.vk.com/?act=logout&hash=29327318c645d49a48&from_host=vk.com&from_protocol=http"

Hash could be different.
How to get this URL?

Comment: Can you assume that the HTML is properly formed XHTML? Or is this any old HTML that may not be in a well-formed XML structure?

Comment: Have you loaded the page into a UIWebView?

Comment: @JimBlackler no, I've loaded it with ASIHTTPRequest in NSString

Answer (score 1):

Since you say the HTML is actually well-formed XHTML, then you can use any XML parsing method to parse the document and find what you are looking for. Using NSXMLParser and a valid parser delegate, you probably would have something like:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"a"] && [[attributeDict objectForKey:@"id"] isEqualToString:@"logoutLink"]) {
        // Found the <a> tag with an id of logoutLink
        NSString *linkURL = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"href"];
        // Do what you want with the link URL here
    }
```

This assumes you are looking for a specific `<a>` element with an id of `logoutLink`. If you are looking for other ways to identify which `<a>` tag has the URL you want you can adjust the `if` statement in this sample code accordingly.

Comment: I tried to make it, but parser stops at <title> tag (before it succesfully parsed 5 more tags). Maybe I was mistaken when said that page is well-formated XHTML.

Comment: To check if it is valid XHTML, try using a validator site such as http://validator.w3.org/

Comment: In that case, you might want to try a library like lib tidy to first cleanup your HTML. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/1527883/830760 for another SO question with some links to libtidy