# HTML tags check in C

Tags: c, parsing

I'm writing a little program in C, for check the HTML file have the right open and close tags?
but i've got some issues...
i have a file what contains the all possible tags, named tags.txt(those are only the first ones):

```
<a>
</a>
<abbr>
</abbr>
<area>
</area>
<aside>
</aside>
```

and i have the htmlfile.html, what I have to check:

```
<!--#echo var="date" -->
<area>
</area>
<area>
</area>
```

secondly, i want to replace the comments like this  to the sysdate
like , the format is OK i can do it, but the prog puts in the file
this

my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 512


void menu();
void check();
void datumos();


int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    menu();

    return 0;
}

void menu()
{
    char menu[MAX_SIZE];
    while(1 < 2)
    {
            printf("\npress a button:\n\n");

                    printf("\tFile HTML check..............:c\n");
                    printf("\t<!--#echo var="date" -->...........:d\n");
                    printf("\tExit:\tCTRL + C\n");
                    scanf("%s",menu);

            if( strcmp(menu,"c") == 0 )
            {
                    check();
            }
            else if( strcmp(menu,"d") == 0 )
            {
                    datumos();
            }

    }
}

void check()
{
    FILE *htmlfile;
    FILE *checkfile;

    htmlfile = fopen("htmlfile.html","w");
    checkfile = fopen("tags.txt","r");

char line[MAX_SIZE];
char htmlline[MAX_SIZE];
char tags[189][30];


int i=0;

printf("\tcheck__1\n");

while(fgets(line,sizeof(line),checkfile) != NULL)
    {

        int j;
    for(j=0; j<sizeof(line); ++j)
    {
        tags[i][j]=line[j];
    }
    ++i;

    }
printf("\tcheck__2\n");


int k=0;    char htmlfiletags[MAX_SIZE][30];
    while(fgets(htmlline,sizeof(htmlline),htmlfile) != NULL)
    {
    char currentline[sizeof(htmlline)];
    int j=0;

        if( currentline[j]=="<" )
        {

                while(currentline[j]!=">") 
                {
                    htmlfiletags[k][j]=currentline[j];
                    ++j;
                }
                strcat(htmlfiletags[k][j+1],">"); 
                ++k; 
        }
}
printf("\tcheck__3\n");


 int n;
 for(n=0; n<sizeof(htmlfiletags); ++n)
 {
     int j; int howmanytimesnot=0;

     for(j=0; j<sizeof(tags); ++j)
     {
         printf("\tcheck__3/1\n");


         if(strcmp(htmlfiletags[n],tags[j])==0)
         {
             printf("\t%d\n", howmanytimesnot);

             ++howmanytimesnot;
         }
     }

    printf("\tcheck__3/3\n");

     if(!(howmanytimesnot<sizeof(tags)))
        {
            printf("\tcheck__3/4\n");
          printf("the file is not wellformed");

          exit (1);
        }

 }
 printf("\tcheck__4\n");


}

void copy_file(const char *from,const char *to)
{
    FILE *fr;
    FILE *t;
    fr = fopen(from,"r");
    t = fopen(to,"w");

    char line[MAX_SIZE];

    char row[MAX_SIZE];

    while(fgets(line,sizeof(line),fr) != NULL)
    {
            sscanf(line,"%s",row);
            fprintf(t,"%s\n",row);
    }

    fclose(fr);
    fclose(t);

    remove("tempfile.html");
 }


void datumos()
{
time_t now = time(NULL);
struct tm *t = localtime(&now);
char date_time[30];
strftime( date_time, sizeof(date_time), "%x_%X", t );

FILE *htmlfile;
    FILE *tempfile;
    htmlfile = fopen("htmlfile.html","r");
    tempfile = fopen("tempfile.html","w");
    char line[MAX_SIZE];
    //char datecomment[]="<!--#echo var=date -->";

    while(fgets(line,sizeof(line),htmlfile) != NULL)
    {

            if( strcmp(line,"<!--#echo var="date" -->") == 0 )
            {

            char row[40];
            strcpy(row,"<!--");
            strcat(row, date_time);
            strcat(row,"-->");

    printf("%s",row);
            fputs(row,tempfile);

            }
            else
            {
                    fputs(line,tempfile);
            }
    }

    fclose(htmlfile);
    fclose(tempfile);

    copy_file("tempfile.html","htmlfile.html");

}
```

it dies in this, in the inner for loop, in the if at the 200th check... i dont know why...

```
 int n;
 for(n=0; n<sizeof(htmlfiletags); ++n)
 {
     int j; int howmanytimesnot=0;

     for(j=0; j<sizeof(tags); ++j)
     {
         printf("\tcheck__3/1\n");


         if(strcmp(htmlfiletags[n],tags[j])==0)
         {
             printf("\t%d\n", howmanytimesnot);

             ++howmanytimesnot;
         }
     }

    printf("\tcheck__3/3\n");

     if(!(howmanytimesnot<sizeof(tags)))
        {
            printf("\tcheck__3/4\n");
          printf("the file is not wellformed");

          exit (1);
        }

 }
```

Thanks for all reply!!
G

Comment: Initial debugger shows that checkfile gets a NULL address.

Comment: Use '<' instead of "<" for characters. Although you do need "<" as a string for strcat().

Comment: A " inside a string literal should be "escaped" that is, preceded by a backslash ->  "Bill \"Big Willie\" Jones"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is very complicated, it has several issues.

Here's one:

```
for(j=0; j<sizeof(tags); ++j)
```

this will not do what I believe you expect; `sizeof(tags)` is not the array length of `tags` (which is declared as `char tags[189][30];`), it's the *total size of the variable*. So, this loop will go from 0 to 189 * 30 - 1, i.e. 5669, and thus index way out beyond the end of array.

Also, the idea to use `sizeof` here in any way is wrong, since the content of `tags` comes from a file and it thus impossible for the compiler to know. Remember that `sizeof` is evaluated at compile-time, for expressions like these.

You need to have a variable (e.g. `size_t num_tags`)  that you increment for each line parsed from the tags file, and that you later use to iterate over `tags`.

Answer (score 0):

[Do not use regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454), or some kind of string parsing, to parse HTML. Instead search the web, [or this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527883/parse-html-using-c), for a c library to parse html. Then check the parsed HTML file for the tags. This will ease the development a lot as you don't have to parse the files yourself.

Comment: yes, i dont want to use regex, this is the point, the tags are stored in a seperated file, this is a specification. that is why i need to compare the tags of the tags.txt and the tags of the htmlfile.html.

Comment: He may not want to use a library or anything either if he's doing this for educational purposes or for better understanding purposes either.

Comment: @GaborToth you can still do that when you use a library, just check the names of the parsed elements. String parsing HTML like this is just very, very bad end error-prone.

Comment: yes, you are totally right. :) i need to learn string and file handling, but i can use only the standard library

Comment: @GaborToth I would start with something more simple than HTML than, correct HTML parsing is very hard. Why not try something simple (my all-time favorite: a text-based RPG). You can for example make a save file with file-io and string parsing.

Answer (score 0):

i've fixed some things, but 
- i still cant check the file's htmltags, dies at the same loop, i've fixed allocation of the tags array
- when in the htmlfile are 2 or more different comments and i'm replacing the  comment the program replaces it with the sysdate, but the program copy the another comments badly, like     =>

the code is now:

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <time.h>

    #define MAX_SIZE 512


    void menu();
    void check();
    void datumos();


    int main(int argc,char *argv[])
    {
        menu();

        return 0;
    }

    void menu()
    {
        char menu[MAX_SIZE];
        while(1 < 2)
        {
                printf("\npress a button:\n\n");

                        printf("\tFile HTML check..............:c\n");
                        printf("\t<!--#echo var="date" -->...........:d\n");
                        printf("\tExit:\tCTRL + C\n");
                        scanf("%s",menu);

                if( strcmp(menu,"c") == 0 )
                {
                        check();
                }
                else if( strcmp(menu,"d") == 0 )
                {
                        datumos();
                }

        }
    }

    void check()
    {
        FILE *htmlfile;
        FILE *checkfile;

        htmlfile = fopen("htmlfile.html","r");
        checkfile = fopen("tags.txt","r");

        char line[MAX_SIZE];
        char htmlline[MAX_SIZE];


        int i2=0;

        printf("\tcheck__1\n");
        while(fgets(line,sizeof(line),checkfile) != NULL)
        {
            ++i2;

        }


        char tags[i2][20];

        int i=0;

        printf("\tcheck__11\n");
        while(fgets(line,sizeof(line),checkfile) != NULL)
        {
            int j;
            for(j=0; j<sizeof(line); ++j)
            {

                tags[i][j]=line[j];
            }
            ++i;

        }
        printf("\tcheck__2\n");

        int k=0;    char htmlfiletags[MAX_SIZE][30];
        while(fgets(htmlline,sizeof(htmlline),htmlfile) != NULL)
        {
            char currentline[sizeof(htmlline)];
            int j=0;

                if( currentline[j]=="<" )
                {

                        while(currentline[j]!=">")
                        {
                            htmlfiletags[k][j]=currentline[j];
                            ++j;
                        }
                        strcat(htmlfiletags[k][j+1],">");
                        ++k;
                }
        }
        printf("\tcheck__3\n");

         int n;
         for(n=0; n<sizeof(htmlfiletags); ++n)
         {
             int j; int howmanytimesnot=0;

             for(j=0; j<sizeof(tags); ++j)
             {
                 //printf("\tcheck__3/1\n");

                 if(strcmp(htmlfiletags[n],tags[j])==0)
                 {
                   //  printf("\t%d\n", howmanytimesnot);
                     ++howmanytimesnot;
                 }
             }

            printf("\tcheck__3/3\n");

             if(!(howmanytimesnot<sizeof(tags)))
                {
                    printf("\tcheck__3/4\n");
                  printf("the file is not wellformed");

                  exit (1);
                }

         }
         printf("\tcheck__4\n");

    }

    void copy_file(const char *from,const char *to)
    {
        FILE *fr;
        FILE *t;
        fr = fopen(from,"r");
        t = fopen(to,"w");

        char line[MAX_SIZE];
        char row[MAX_SIZE];

        while(fgets(line,sizeof(line),fr) != NULL)
        {
            sscanf(line,"%s",row);
            fprintf(t,"%s\n",row);
        }

        fclose(fr);
        fclose(t);

        remove("tempfile.html");
    }


    void datumos()
    {
    time_t now = time(NULL);
    struct tm *t = localtime(&now);
    char date_time[30];
    strftime( date_time, sizeof(date_time), "%x_%X", t );

        FILE *htmlfile;
        FILE *tempfile;

        htmlfile = fopen("htmlfile.html","r");
        tempfile = fopen("tempfile.html","w");

        char line[MAX_SIZE];
        char* datecomment="<!--#echo var=\"date\" -->";

        while(fgets(line,sizeof(line),htmlfile) != NULL)
        {

            int i3; int db=0;
            for(i3=0; i3<strlen(datecomment); ++i3)
            {
                if(line[i3]==datecomment[i3])
                {
                    ++db;
                }

            }

            if(db==strlen(datecomment))
            {

            char row[30];
            strcpy(row,"<!--");
            strcat(row, date_time);
            strcat(row,"-->\n");

            fputs(row,tempfile);

            }
            else
            {
                fputs(line,tempfile);
            }

        }

        fclose(htmlfile);
        fclose(tempfile);

        copy_file("tempfile.html","htmlfile.html");

    }
```

Comment: so it replaces <!--#echo var="date" --> to the sysdate, it's ok, but when there are different comments like <!--#include something -->, it wont be copied back well, in the htmlfile will be only <!--#include

Answer (score 0):

- the currentline it's not necessary,and i've fixed the compares too

  ```
  while(fgets(htmlline,sizeof(htmlline),htmlfile) != NULL)
  {           
      int j=0;

          if( htmlline[j]=='<' )
          {

                  while(htmlline[j]!='>')
                  {
                      htmlfiletags[k][j]=htmlline[j];
                      ++j;
                  }
                  strcat(htmlfiletags[k][j+1],">");
                  ++k;
          }
  }
  ```

-in addition, the another problem to replace only the suitable comments, and dont hurt the different ones still dont work

"so it replaces

```
  <!--#echo var="date" --> to the sysdate, it's ok, but when there are different comments like

  <!--#include something -->, it wont be copied back well, in the htmlfile will be only <!--#include"
```

ideas?