# Parsing HTML using libxml2 gives entity ref issue

Tags: html, c, libxml2

I'm trying to write a small program to extract some data from a web page using libxml2. Since the data is local in an HTML file, I decided to use the following as a starting point to get the HTML into a traversable memory structure:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    htmlDocPtr dp = htmlReadFile(argv[1], NULL, HTML_PARSE_RECOVER | HTML_PARSE_NONET );
```

However, when I run this passing the HTML file as a parameter, I get an error:

```
HTML parser error : htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';'
```

What it seems to be complaining about is the following:

```
<a href="do_something.html?a=1&b=2"> some stuff </a>
```

i.e. rather than ignore the contents of the `href` attribute or treat it as a URL with parameters, it seems to be treating the bit from `&b` as an entity reference like *&name;* and complaining that there's no semicolon. Surely that's not right? Should I be doing something different to get it to ignore this (I'm not interested in these tags in any case) or have I just missed the point somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input file is invalid, because it contains invalid url. See [point 2.2 in RFC 3986 - Reserved characters](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2). Ampersand should be escaped using percent sign escapes, and question mark too. A legal url would look like this:

```
<a href="do_something.html%3Fa%3D1%26b%3D2"> some stuff </a>
```

But it's only one of a long list of traps when trying to parse html. The usual approach is to use a tidying library, see this question: [Parse html using C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1527883/772981). The goal is to clear errors in html before actual parsing.

Comment: Yes, you're right. this isn't the first error in this (supposedly xhtml conformant) page. Thanks very much for the links - I'll follow them up.