# Parsing HTML files in C - alternatives to libxml2

Tags: c, web-crawler, libxml2

So I want to create a web crawler in C. There are hardly any libraries to support this.
I can use **libtidy** to convert HTML to XHTML and get the HTML files using **libcurl** (which has decent documentation).

My problem is parsing the HTML files and getting all the links present in it. I know **libxml2** 
is there but its extremely hard to understand because there is no good documentation for its API.

Should I even do this in C or go with another language like Java ?
Or are there any good alternatives to **libxml2** ?

Comment: You can also look at [expat](http://www.jclark.com/xml/expat.html), Source - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399704/xml-parser-for-c. Also take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527883/parse-html-using-c

Comment: possible duplicate of [XML Parser for C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/399704/xml-parser-for-c)

Comment: [No good documentation for libxml2?](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/index.html)

Comment: You can't rely upon XML compliance when crawling the web. So XML parsers won't help much

Comment: It might be a dumb question, but can it also parse XHTML ?

Comment: XHTML is xml isnt it? I dont see any reason why not then.

Comment: yes, but only few sites are XHTML. Most are messy HTML

Comment: You could write your own crawler code, if you want a very customized solution. :)

Comment: HTML is **not** xml or even related to xml so an xml parser is useless.

Comment: If `libtidy` converts HTML to XHTML, then an XML parser might be usable on the output.  Whether that's sufficient, efficient or sensible is another matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing HTML requires basically just string manipulation.

But it's quite hard to do without an HTML or XML (if it's XHTML) parser.

As for the second part of the question I woudn't choose C for such task because even basic string operations are much complex than many other languages that support them natively.

I would go for a scripting lanuguage such Python, JavaScript, PHP...

Instead of using libcurl you'll invoke curl as a command line tool.

Btw: libcurl documentation is very good (in my opinion).

Comment: Yes libcurl documentation is really good. I don't want to invoke curl from system() because it will invoke another shell process which I do not want. I will look into regex :) Thank you

Comment: You can not parse HTML with regex. Regular expressions are not powerful enough to handle HTML, which is a context-free grammar.
See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) and [this](http://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/).

Comment: Changing your answer to remove your original suggestion that you should use regex is all well, but downvoting half a dozen of my answers because you're upset shows that you're dishonest and you lack integrity.