# Find the tags in a file using pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

So I am quite new to using pointers, and as such maybe what I'm trying doesn't even make sense...? I am working on a project that asks me to find html tags in a file by searching for the start and end points of the tags (being read in from a file).

Currently, I have the entire file written into a 1 dimensional char array and I must search through the array finding any tag starting and ending with the identifiers '<' and  '>' strictly using pointers. If there is a '/' or white space between the identifiers then it is not a tag, and we do not need to keep a reference of it. The array is set up in such a way that it does keep the formatting of the initial file.

Once a tag is found we must search the array for matches and count how many of the same tags there are. I am restricted from storing the found tags in an array but I am able to store the pointer to the start and end of each tag in a pointer array. Any guidance would be appreciated. This is the code I have that has it working probably, but I want to get some practice with pointers...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *fptr;
    char maxLength[10] = "";// this is where each tag less than 10 characters long will be held
    char htags[100][10]; // Array that will be used to store each tag found
    int tagCounts[100]; // Array that will count the amount of times a tag shows up
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        tagCounts[i] = 0;
    int n = 0;
    char *filename = argv[1]; // Input file to be read
    fptr = fopen(filename, "r"); // Read through the file
    if (fptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("File not found...");
        return 0;
    }
int c;
    if (fptr != NULL)
    {
        while (c = fgetc(fptr) != NULL)// making sure we are reading until the very end of the file
        {
            char c = fgetc(fptr); // reading character by character

            if (c == '<' && !feof(fptr))// searching for tags that start with '<'
            {
                char ch = fgetc(fptr);
                if (ch != '/') // checking to see if it is actually a tag
                {
                    int i = 0;
                    strcpy(maxLength, ""); // this is what we will use to store the tags when we find one
                    while (ch != 10 && ch != '>' && ch != ' ')
                    {
                        maxLength[i] = ch; // adds the next character to str[] until
                        // it gets to the end of the tag
                        ch = fgetc(fptr);
                        i++; // increment i so that the characters don't overlap in the array
                    }

                    maxLength[i] = '\0'; // Used to indicate the termination of the character string for a tag

                    int number = 1;

                    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)// Checking to see if the tag has already
                                               // been found before in the file
                    {
                        if (strcmp(htags[i], maxLength) == 0) // tag has been found before
                        {
                            tagCounts[i]++; // increase the count by 1
                            number = 0;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (number == 1)
                    {
                        strcpy(htags[n], maxLength); // store the newly found tag in the array
                        tagCounts[n]++;
                        n++; // A new tag has been found, so we must create another element in the array and subsequently increase it's count
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("Tag-> %s -> Appeared %d time(s)\n", htags[i], tagCounts[i]);
    }
}
```

Above is what the program should do (take in a text file and count the tags), but now I must strictly be using pointers to reference the elements in the array, get the string between and then count the similar ones...

The arrays I have initialized for the below program are:

```
char buffer[100000]; 
char *sTags[100], *eTags[100];
```

This is what I was able to come up with, but I have just hit a wall in my understanding of the material.

```
    char *contents = buffer;    

    if(buffer != NULL){
       char *c = contents;

        if(*c == '<'){
            char *ch = contents;

            if(*ch != '/'){
                while(*ch != '\0' && *ch != '>' && *ch != ' '){
                    contents++; //nothing is telling us it isn't a tag, so find the end
                    //found the tag, so get the location right before it?
                    if(*ch == '>'){
                        *sTags = contents--;
                    }
                    *sTags = '\0';
                }
                //This is where I am confused.
                //How would I go about comparing the string to other strings
                //throughout the file if it is not stored somewhere..?
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%s", sTags);
```

Comment: The printf at the bottom is there just to see if I was getting anything from it

Comment: Note that [`while (!feof(file))` is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431941/15168).

Comment: The code in `main()` was abysmally formatted.  I've reformatted it to my preferred conventions — you can redo the formatting to your preferred conventions as long as the result is recognizable.

Comment: This code `int tagCounts[100]; /* Array that will count the amount of times a tag shows up */
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        tagCounts[i] = 0;` could be replaced by `int tagCounts[100] = { 0 }; /* Array that will count the number of times a tag shows up */`.

Comment: Noted, had no idea that's how !feof() acted, been away from coding for a few years now. Only just jumping back into C, still lots to learn.

Comment: If are looking for tags in some arbitrary file . . . then  . . . okay . . . but if you are actually parsing a HTML file, you'll probably find it worth your while to use a parser.  If the file is all valid HTML, this article might be an interesting read for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527883/parse-html-using-c

Comment: That's way above my level haha, I'm just trying to read through a regular txt file, that I have read into an array and count each occurrence of a tag. i.e <body> <html> <b> etc. unlike the first example I gave though I can't store the tags I find as strings in an array and simply compare using strcmp() to count them. I can only have an array that holds the start and end point of each tag found. I don't know how to go about getting the substring between the "< >" though with pointers and nothing to compare with?

Answer (score 1):

Two things to consider.

### 1) isspace(c)

You may want to use isspace(c) instead of c == ' '.
https://www.techonthenet.com/c_language/standard_library_functions/ctype_h/isspace.php

Because it seems like checking for (c == ' ') will allow tags that cross ends of lines.
For example, what would your code do with a four line file like this?

```
<alpha>
<be
ta>
<gamma>
```

Would it find find tags like "<alpha>", "<be\nta>", and "<gamma>" ?
Hmm... Is that what you're checking (c == 10) for ?

### 2) strncmp()

I don't completey understand the pointers-only requirement of not storing copies of tags.
But strncmp() might help. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strncmp.htm
If you have the beginning and end pointers of a tag then the lenth is (end-beg+1).

So in your first kind of longish main() method you're looping over known tags, if any, to check for matches.

Your pointer-based one can loop over your known tags and you only need to call strncmp()
if the candidate tag is the same length as a known tag.

### Lastly

Lastly, bonus points for printf() debugging, I find those super useful in my code.
Don't hesitate to print things out.

And if you don't already have a small test file for debugging I'd encourage you to make one.

Good luck!

Comment: Hmm..seems like I got a lot more work ahead of me than I had anticipated. As for the not storing copies, it's just to get used to how pointers act, but the first one does manage to catch everything. Assuming they are under 10 characters, the file had been written in that way.  And I hadn't thought about the <be \n ta> situation... which I do not think is caught atm.. but just using pointers to better understand how they actually work. I'll get to work on the recommendations!

Comment: Hmm... if you can modify your buffer you could overwrite the '>' in tags like "...<foo>..." and change it to "...<foo\0..." and just store the address of (pointer to) 'f'. Then it would be easier to use strcmp() on what is essentially a pointer to the string "foo", just buried inside the other chars.