# Extract all URLs from HTML in C

Tags: html, c, regex, string

How can I extract all URLs in a HTML using C standard library?

I am trying to deal with it using sscanf(), but the valgrind gives error (and I am even not sure if the code can meet my requirement after debugging successfully, so if there are other ways, please tell me). I stored the html content in a string pointer, there are multiple URLs (including absolute URL and relative URL, e.g.http://www.google.com, //www.google.com, /a.html, a.html and so on) in it. I want to extract them one by one and store them separately into another string pointer.

I am also thinking about using strstr(), but then I have no idea about how to get the second url.

My code (I skip the assert here) using sscanf:

```
int
main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char *remain_html = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 1001);
    char *url = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 101);

    char *html = "<A HREF=\"http://www.google.com\">navigation</a>"
                 "<a href=\"/a.html\">search</a>";
    printf("html: %s\n\n", html);

    sscanf(html, "<a href=\"%s", remain_html);
    printf("after first href tag: %s\n\n", remain_html);
    sscanf(remain_html, "%s\">", url);
    printf("first web: %s\n\n", url);
    sscanf(remain_html, "<a href=\"%s", remain_html);
    printf("after second href tag: %s\n\n", remain_html);

    free(remain_html);
    free(url);
}
```

The valgrind gives: Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s).

If anybody could help, thank you so much!

Comment: Is your question the first sentence in your post, or how to fix the error at the bottom?

Comment: Because the error is very clear, but to understand it, you have to know what the words "conditional," "jump," "move" and "unitialised" mean.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? [Parse html using C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1527883/1115360) dates back to 2009. Also, the answers to [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/1115360) contain information on why regexes and HTML don't go together.

Comment: @Robert Harvey The first sentence is my final goal. I tried to solve it by the following code, and it gives error. What I ask is if my code can gives out my desire, how to modify it and fix the bug, if not, what will be a feasible way to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*valgrind* warn you about non initialized data (used in test), considering your program only does *sscanf* and *printf* that means you very probably have a problem with your *scanf*

if I change a little your program to print the result of *sscanf*, so show much elements it get :

```
int
main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char *remain_html = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 1001);
    char *url = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 101);

    char *html = "<A class=\"mw-jump-link\" HREF=\"#mw-head\">Jump to navigation</a>"
                     "<a class=\"mw-jump-link\" href=\"#p-search\">Jump to search</a>";
    printf("html: %s\n\n", html);

    printf("%d\n", sscanf(html, "<a href=\"%s", remain_html));
    printf("after first href tag: %s\n\n", remain_html);
    printf("%d\n", sscanf(remain_html, "%s\">", url));
    printf("first web: %s\n\n", url);
    printf("%d\n", sscanf(remain_html, "<a href=\"%s", remain_html));
    printf("after second href tag: %s\n\n", remain_html);

    free(remain_html);
    free(url);
}
```

the execution is :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
html: <A class="mw-jump-link" HREF="#mw-head">Jump to navigation</a><a class="mw-jump-link" href="#p-search">Jump to search</a>

0
after first href tag: 

-1
first web: 

-1
after second href tag: 

pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

so the first *scanf* got nothing (0 element), that means it does not set *remain_html* and that one is non initialized when it is used by the next *sscanf* with an undefined behavior

Because of the format

> ```
> "<a href=\"%s"
> ```

the first *sscanf* waits for a string starting by

```
 <a href="
```

but *html* starts by

> ```
> <A class=
> ```

which is different, so it stop from the second character and does not set *remain_html*

---

To use *sscanf* is not the right way, search for the prefix *<a href="* may be in uppercase for instance using *strcasestr*, then extract the URL up to the closing "

Example :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

/* in case you do not have that function */
char * strcasestr(char * haystack, char *needle)
{
  while (*haystack) {
    char * ha = haystack;
    char * ne = needle;

    while (tolower(*ha) == tolower(*ne)) {
      if (!*++ne)
        return haystack;
      ha += 1;
    }
    haystack += 1;
  }

  return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  char *html = "<A HREF=\"http://www.google.com\">navigation</a>"
               "<a href=\"/a.html\">search</a>";
  char * begin = html;
  char * end;

  printf("html: %s\n", html);

  while ((begin = strcasestr(begin, "<a href=\"")) != NULL) {
    begin += 9; /* bypass the header */
    end = strchr(begin, '"');

    if (end != NULL) {
      printf("found '%.*s'\n", (int) (end - begin), begin);
      begin = end + 1;
    }
    else {
      puts("invalid url");
      return -1;
    }
  }
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -Wall a.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
html: <A HREF="http://www.google.com">navigation</a><a href="/a.html">search</a>
found 'http://www.google.com'
found '/a.html'
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Note I know the second parameter of *strcasestr* is in lower case so it is useless to do do *tolower(*ne)* and **ne* is enough, but I given a definition of the function out of the current context

Comment: Sorry I changed to inappropriate html for some reasons, but if the given html contains two satisfied string, it also gives that error.

Comment: @Emmm what is the new html ?

Comment: There are several urls in the string in <a href=""> tag, and the urls including both  absolute url and relative url, e.g. http://www.google.com, //www.google.com, /a.html, a.html.

Comment: @Emmm  I cannot do something from a description, what is exactly the new value for *html* ?

Comment: It's quite long.. The part of it would be: <div class="menuitem">
<a href="http://www.ibdhost.com/help/path/">URL Paths
<br/>
Absolute vs. Relative Path </a>
</div><br/>

<div class="menuitem">
<a href="/submit/">Submit Sites
<br/>to Search Engines</a>
</div><br/>

Comment: that still does not starts by "<a href=" as expected by the first *sscanf**

Comment: **sscanf** if not the right way to parse your input

Comment: @Emmm I edited my answer to give you a proposal doing the job

Comment: @Emmm you seems not interrested by my answer, so I delete it ?

Comment: Sorry that I didn't check the message, since dealt with other things. Thanks for your answer, so I think I get the point that only when I know exactly the start and end, then I can use sscanf? So in my situation, I need to use strcasestr to find the start.

Comment: @Emmm yes *scanf* is a very limited parser and when you have explicit string (out of %) it must be exactly that string. In that case *scanf* cannot be used